# What is the difference between Scaldi and Guice

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, scaldi

I am now working in a project that uses **Scaldi**, I am learning it, and looks good so far, but I still did not figure out the actual functionalities that it offers over **guide/juice.**

What are the actual differences between the 2 frameworks?

Is Scaldi more functional oriented?

What do I lose/gain if I move from one to the other?

Answer (score 6):

> Guice is a java library, so its also implemented in terms of java
>   idioms and common patterns (it heavily uses annotations and
>   reflection). Scaldi from the other hand is implemented in terms of
>   common patterns and idioms of Scala. So it uses implicit parameters,
>   type classes, macros, type tags, etc. One important goal of scaldi was
>   to avoid use of annotations, reflection and runtime bytecode
>   manipulation. Even though very small portion of it uses scala
>   reflection, for the most part it's reflection-free. This means that
>   you are in charge of instantiation of your classes (it's not done via
>   reflection). As a direct result of it, scaldi uses implicit Injector
>   parameter, which is necessary for the implementation of
>   annotation/reflection-free injection mechanism. Scaldi also has
>   several features that I haven't seen in guice, like [conditional bindings](http://scaldi.org/learn/#conditions), [property injector](http://scaldi.org/learn/#property-injector) or [macro for constructor injector](http://scaldi.org/learn/#constructor-injection) (which
>   is similar to macwire, but uses scaldi's injection mechanism).

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scaldi/TYU36h7kGqk)